# How to provide parameters to a submake when running in parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to use make to handle some data processing.

Consider the following simple rule in a makefile `makefile-month`

```
output_$(YEAR)_$(MONTH): input_$(YEAR)_$(MONTH)
    foo input_$(YEAR)_$(MONTH) output_$(YEAR)_$(MONTH)
```

This rule can be used to process any required month using, e.g.

```
make -f makefile-month YEAR=2006 MONTH=2
```

And this works fine.

What I am really interested now is to use make to process several months in parallel.
However, I cannot find a simple way of achieving this.

Notice that using a shell for loop does not work with parallel make.
Defining a global makefile,

```
all:
    for year in 2006; do \
        for month in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12; do \
            $(MAKE) -f makefile-month YEAR=$$year MONTH=$$month; \
        done; \
    done
```

and running,

```
make -j 12
```

does not execute each month in parallel.
Each call to the sub-make is executed in serial.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of different ways to handle the details, but the overall solution is to move away from for loops in a single recipe and switch to individual targets.  So for example:

```
YEARS := 2006 2007
MONTHS := 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

TARGETS := $(foreach Y,$(YEARS),$(foreach M,$(MONTHS),month.$Y.$M))

.PHONY: all $(TARGETS)
all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS):
        $(MAKE) -f makefile-month YEAR=$(word 2,$(subst ., ,$@)) MONTH=$(word 3,$(subst ., ,$@))
```

(note I didn't test this but hopefully you get the idea).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. This seems to work fine. The idea is to encode all parameters in a fictitious task, and then to decode the parameters again from the task name when calling the sub-make. I wonder if there is any other way of solving this problem where you don't have to do this unnecessary encoding/decoding

Comment: Yes, there are other ways, but I don't think any of them are cleaner.  They ALL will involve, as I said in my answer, putting each invocation in a separate target.  That's simply the only way to get parallelism in make: it only parallelizes individual targets never commands within a single recipe.  There are other possible ways to specify the value of YEAR and MONTH, but they involve writing out each target individually so that those values can be assigned on a per target basis.  Of course you can make this happen programmatically, you don't have to do it by hand.